How is NFS Undercover linked with the other parts?
In the beginning of NFS Undercover you're being chased by cops. Does this has to do with the ending of a previous NFS or is it just because we're an undercover cop and our in the city isn't as suspicious?

Does this answer your question? Is there story continuity between various Need For Speed games?

@pinckerman This question is much more specific, and (while answers shouldn't be used when deciding whether some question is a dupe or not) the answer doesn't mention Undercover. VTLO.

@Joachim I get it, but Undercover is also part of that question, and seems quite a dupe to me

@pinckerman I get that too :)
